# Duplicating transaction splits in gnucash?

Tags: gnucash

I've imported 4 years of banking history into gnucash. I have regular transactions which I'd like to split into categories (which I understand are "accounts" in gnucash terms). For example:

```
$400 - biweekly deposit from Mars
```

splits into these categories, which I've defined as sub-accounts to my Savings account:

```
$200 - Assets:Savings:House fund
$150 - Assets:Savings:Savings
$ 45 - Assets:Savings:Auto insurance
$  5 - Assets:Savings:Mad money
```

What's the most efficient method to duplicate this template to the hundred or so transactions waiting to be split?

Comment: I suppose the question behind the question is *"how does one do batch or bulk edits in gnucash?"*

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, there is no facility to do bulk transaction edits in GnuCash, so you are out of luck for your existing hundred. (I don't know whether there is a way to initially import a transaction as split.)

However, once you have entered this split once, it can be used as a template for **new** transactions, using autocomplete or by entering it in the Scheduled Transaction Editor.

Comment: no bulk edits. yuk (but thanks for letting me know I wasn't just missing something!). I spent a few hours trying to import and split without success; basic method was to import 1 or 2 records, define the splits, and then import again with the whole lot. No luck, it auto-matched, but ignored the splits. Kmymoney handles this kind of thing *much* better, but on my Windows 7 machines crashes way to often to consider for this kind of work.

Answer (score 2):

After several hours of trying to get various import methods to work (see comment to other answer), I ended up just adding all the splits by just gritting my teeth, against the inefficiency of at all, and entered them manually. The process took a couple hours, but at least now I have clean data.

Duplicating an existing transaction with splits and just changing the date is (a lot) more keyboard efficient than editing an existing transaction and adding the splits (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>, `1/1/2011`) even when accounting for the overhead of deleting the now-duplicate imported transaction (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).